# How do you run "source" when starting a shell?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, bashrc, login-script

In order to use rvm (https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/), I need to run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

each time when I start a new shell.  How do I automatically do this when I start my computer, rather than having to type it each time?

This is my .bash_profile:

```
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
 # Load RVM into a shell session *as a fu    nction*
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
 # Load RVM function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options here:

1. Put the contents of your .bash_profile in ~/.bashrc.
2. Add `source ~/.bash_profile` to ~/.bashrc.
3. Add `[ -e ~/.bash_profile ] && source ~/.bash_profile` to your /etc/bashrc
4. If you are switching users (e.g. with `sudo` or `su`), specify that you want a login environment to be loaded (e.g. with `su -` instead of just `su`).

Background: .bash_profile is specific to login shells, whereas .bashrc is loaded by all shells.  So you're either missing the logic that causes .bash_profile to be loaded in the first place, or you're not launching a **login** shell when you're launching your shell.

Comment: thanks! it works! "Add source ~/.bash_profile to ~/.bashrc."

Answer (score 1):

At the end of my .bash_profile I have this line:

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

I tried using what you have in your bash profile (which is part of the instructions for setting up rvm) but I could never get it to work.